# Interaction of parametric types and multiple dispatch in Julia

Tags: types, parameters, julia

**Setup:** Consider a parametric type in Julia

```
type MyType1{T1}
    x::T1
end
```

I define two methods for a single function over this type using multiple dispatch and type parameters:

```
f1(m::MyType1, i::Int64) = m.x + i #Method 1
f1{T1}(m::MyType1, i::T1) = m.x + i + 1 #Method 2
```

Method 1 corresponds to the case where the second input is `Int64`. Method 2 corresponds to the case where the second input is parametric. I create an instance of `MyType1` using `m=MyType1{Int64}(1)` and note that `m.x` now returns `1`.

**Question 1:** I witness the following behaviour:

```
In  : f1(m, 1.0)

Out : 3.0
```

Okay, so I didn't provide any info about `T1` in the function call. It seems Julia inferred that it should perform Method 2 on the grounds that the second input *wasn't* an `Int64`. Is this how things are actually working under the hood?

**Question 2:** Let's say I want to call the second method, but with the second input as an `Int64`. Obviously `f1(m, 1)` won't work as it will call the first method. I tried this:

```
In   : f1{Int64}(m, 1)
```

But Julia throws this error:

```
ERROR: type: instantiate_type: expected TypeConstructor, got Function
```

Is it possible to get the second method to run with the second input specified as `Int64`, or am I being silly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm wondering if you meant to have the first argument in the second method typed as `m::MyType1{T1}`, e.g.

```
f1{T1}(m::MyType1{T1}, i::T1) = m.x + i + 1 #Method 2b
```

This means that the second method will only be applicable if `i` has the same type as the type parameter of `T1` of the type of `m`. With your original definition, `T1` will just be matched to whatever type the actual argument `i` has, so you might as well have written it `f1(m::MyType1, i::Any) = ...`.

**1)** Using Method 2b instead of Method 2, I get

```
julia> f1(m, 1.0)
ERROR: no method f1(MyType1{Int64}, Float64)
```

since there's no method that applies.
In your original case, Method 1 doesn't apply but Method 2 does. Julia picks the most specific method that applies, e.g. Method 2. So yes, you can say that Method 2 is picked because the second input wasn't an `Int64`.

**2)** Explicit type parameters are (at least so far) only supported on types, not function calls. The `invoke` function allows to call a specified function and pick the method based on a given (more general) list of argument types, but I'm not sure if applies here since for `MyType{Int64}`, the two methods apply to exactly the same types for the second argument. Either way, it not recommended to use `invoke` is general, and I think it can give a pretty big performance penalty.

If you really want to be able to call Method 2 in this case, you should find another way where you don't have to fight multiple dispatch. One option would be to to pull out the implementation of Method 2 into its own function, e.g.

```
f1(m::MyType1, i::Int64)      = m.x + i  #Method 1
f1{T1}(m::MyType1{T1}, i::T1) = g1(m, i) #Method 2b
g1{T1}(m::MyType1{T1}, i::T1) = m.x + i + 1
```

The you can call `g1` directly if you want to use the second method.

Btw, any specific reason that you are using `Int64`? Unless you explicitly need 64 bits, using `Int` (which is typealiased to either `Int32` or `Int64` depending on your system) is more Julian and tends to interoperate a little better with other code.

Comment: You are correct, I was trying to implement your Method 2b. I'm a Matlab convert so still learning as far as types are concerned. No specific reason for `Int64`. I'll happily switch to `Int` if there is no performance hit. Does the same rule apply for `Float` (i.e. use `Float` instead of `Float64`)? ps Thanks for the answer +1+Tick. Very clear, and it is exactly what I was after.

Comment: No, for floats you have to specify `Float64` or `Float32`. The reason is that the decision which type to use is rarely based on machine type, but needed precision.